# Issue with drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a problem with my drop down list populating one of the fields. Basically it's meant to pull the user logged in or the user who's linked to a certain project.

I have 3 drop downs on the page and 2 of them return results from the db, one dosent and I aint sure why, It could be and most likely is something in the sql command or the c# backend code, if I paste the code, if someone could help me identify the problem that would be great.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Registered Users/My Projects/MyProjectsMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Ratings.aspx.cs" Inherits="Registered_Users_My_Projects_Ratings" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
        </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
        <h1>Project Manager Reviews Page</h1>
        <asp:Label ID="uname" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="uid" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownProjects" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceProject" 
                DataTextField="project_id" DataValueField="project_id" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ProjectSelected"></asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceProject" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ScrumString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT project_title FROM projects INNER JOIN project_managers ON projects.project_id = 
                project_managers.project_id INNER JOIN users ON project_managers.user_id = users.id WHERE user_id = @uid" 
                OnSelecting="SqlDataSourceProject_Selecting">
                <SelectParameters>
                     <asp:Parameter Name="uid"/>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>


            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSprints" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SprintSelected" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSprints" DataTextField="project_id" DataValueField="project_id">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSprints" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ScrumString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [sprints]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListUsers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceUsers" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserSelected" DataTextField="username" DataValueField="username">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceUsers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ScrumString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [username] FROM [users]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The C# code is as follows..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;

public partial class Registered_Users_My_Projects_Ratings : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String userName = Session["UserLoggedOn"].ToString();
        uname.Text = userName;
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ScrumString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        myConnection.Open();

        String userIDQuery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username= '" + userName + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(userIDQuery, myConnection);
        String usrIDAsString = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        Int32 uidresult = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        uid.Text = Convert.ToString(uidresult);
        SqlDataSourceProject.SelectParameters.Add("@uid", uid.Text);

        myConnection.Close();


    }
```

Sorry if the code isnt well presented, I wasnt exactly sure how to go about forming it correctly..

Any help would be great..

Thanks

Comment: Which one is not working?

Comment: also your `runat =Server` should be `runat="server"` in this line `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">`

Comment: you need to use `Parameterized Query's` properly.. are you familiar with using the debugger..? step through the code and I think you will see where your problem is happening..

Comment: Im trying to pass the text from the label called uid to that select parameter @MethodMan

Comment: Not sure @Olivier De Meulder, think honestly its with the asp page, something in the select command might be off probably with the inner joins..

Comment: I would try running the query outside of the web page and see if it returns any data using Sql Server Management Studio can you verify that the query works if you run it outside the app..?

Comment: We have taken out the uid at the end of the query and have tested it in management studio and it pulls the title and ID as we want it to, so we arent sure if its something with the query after that or the code behind @MethodMan

Comment: I would personally refactor that code to use stored procedure database calls within C# what you are doing in regards to populating data , Binding etc.. is a bit bulky in all due respect.. is that an option..? perhaps it's an Event issue and or a PostBack() issue.. I can think of a few better ways to do what you are trying to do.. too much mixing and matching in my opinion..

Comment: why 2 to 3 times converting one value and second thing get useris or username from table and bind userid to value field . it should be work.

Comment: @MethodMan I think with a bit of persistence I managed to get it to display the project title,I had to play about with the select command and change things but it looks to be pulling that out now, just need to fix the rest of the dropdown to pull out the correct data, what would be the best way in your opinion of doing this, like you said you would have better ways of doing this and would most likely confuse me less